# How to embed a power bi report inside a project detail page on a sharepoint site? (complete on-premises setup without office 365 tenant)

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, ms-project, power-bi-report-server, on-premises-instances

I'm using a Power BI pro desktop client 2020 to create my reports from PWA. I have a on-premises Power BI report server 2020 to publish my reports. And I have a Sharepoint server on premises version 2019. I have enabled project server 2019 and I have a PWA enabled as well. Now, I'm trying to embed my powerBI report inside a PDP (completely on-premises).

I do not have an office 365 tenant as a result I do not have Power BI webpart to embed it as a webpart, I do not have iframe options as well inside my installation. I do not get options to add a page as well inside my sharepoint site.

Do I have to enable something to get these options in my sharepoint site, please? And how do I achieve this - embedding my report in an on-premises server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by adding an `iframe` with report's embedded URL as a source. For any Power BI Report Server report URL, add the following query string parameter to embed your report in a SharePoint iFrame: `?rs:embed=true`.

For example: `https://myserver/reports/powerbi/Sales?rs:embed=true`.

Navigate to a SharePoint Site Contents page:

[image]

Choose the page where you want to add your report:

[image]

Select the gear icon on the top right, and then select Edit page:

[image]

Select Add a Web Part. Under Categories, select Media and Content. Under Parts, select Content Editor, and then select Add:

[image]

Select Click here to add new content. From the top menu, select Format Text, and then select Edit Source:

[image]

In the Edit Source window, paste your iFrame code in HTML Source, and then select OK:

[image]

For example:

```
<iframe width="800" height="600" src="https://myserver/reports/powerbi/Sales?rs:embed=true" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

In the top menu, select Page, and then select Stop Editing:

[image]

The report appears on the page:

[image]

See [Embed a Power BI Report Server report using an iFrame in SharePoint Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed).

Comment: Thanks @Andrey I tried this solution, I get the iframe inside the PDP page successfully but there is some security settings error. But other than that solution appears to be working for me. Thank you so much. I will try experimenting further to resolve security settings error for the page

Comment: It worked @Andrey Nikolov. Thank you so much. Next, I have further questions out of scope of this question. My report server url is not same as my fqdn, which triggers CORS error - this is the reason I had errors (I tried the same with similar fqdn- it worked without any errors). Any thoughts about how to handle it, please?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not have experience in web development. Ask a new question, so someone else can pick it up and answer you.